# Rookie test bencher, can't make head or tail of errors. (Using Icarus Verilog)

Tags: verilog, hdl, servo

I've been trying to get this code that I whipped up on a whim. For the most part, I think I'm sure the modules themselves are okay. Its the test bench that's throwing up all the errors.

Here's the code in its entirety:

```
/*
Primitive code to control a stepper motor using FPGA
It will run as a seconds hand
9 June 2016
dwiref024
*/

module clock_divider(clock, reset, clock_div);

input clock;
input reset;

output clock_div;
reg [25:0]counter = 26'd0;

// Assuming a clock frequency of 40Mhz
// log2(40M) = 25.25
// Therefore 40MHz corresponds to MOD25
always@(posedge clock, negedge reset)   begin
    if(!reset) begin
        counter <= 26'd0;   
    end

    if(counter == 26'd40000000) begin
        counter <= 26'd0;
    end

    else begin
    counter <= counter + 1;
    end

end

assign clock_div = counter[24]; // Gives you a clock signal 'clock_div'of approximate frequency 1Hz

initial begin
    $dumpvars(0, clock, reset, counter);
end
endmodule

module count_seconds (
input clock_div, reset
);
reg [5:0]seconds = 6'd0;

always@(posedge clock_div, negedge reset) begin
    if (!reset) begin
        seconds <= 0;
    end
    else if (seconds == 6'd60) begin
        seconds <= 0;
    end

    else begin
        seconds <= seconds + 1;
    end
end
initial begin
    $dumpvars (0, clock_div, seconds);
end

endmodule

module get_servo(
input clock_div,
output reg servoPin = 0, 
output reg ding
);

always@(posedge clock_div)  begin
    if(clock_div)
        ding <= 1;
    else
        ding <= 0;
end
always@(ding)   begin

    if (ding) begin
        servoPin = 1'b1;
    end
    else servoPin = 1'b0;
end


initial begin
    $dumpvars (0, servoPin);
end

endmodule

module clk_tb;
reg clock;
reg reset;
reg servoPin;
reg clock_div;
reg ding;
initial begin
    clock = 0;
    reset = 0;  
    repeat(2) #10 clock = ~clock;
    reset = 1;
    forever #10 clock = ~clock; 
end

clock_divider DUT1 (clock, reset, clock_div);
get_servo DUT2 (clock_div, servoPin, ding);

initial begin
    servoPin = 1'b1;
    #1 clock_div = 1'b0;
    $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Upon running

```
$ icarusverilog -o servo servo.v
```

I get the following errors:

```
servo.v:105: error: reg clock_div; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
servo.v:105: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
servo.v:105:      : Port 3 (clock_div) of clock_divider is connected to clock_div
servo.v:106: error: reg servoPin; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
servo.v:106: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
servo.v:106:      : Port 2 (servoPin) of get_servo is connected to servoPin
servo.v:106: error: reg ding; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
servo.v:106: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
servo.v:106:      : Port 3 (ding) of get_servo is connected to ding
6 error(s) during elaboration.
```

I looked across the boards here and saw questions that specified when and where you use reg in the test bench modules to avoid the this:

```
<variable name> is not a valid l-value in foo
```

That was among the first errors that I got. In trying to avoid it, I have ended up with these. 
If anyone could point out the root cause of these errors and where they originate from, I might be able to fix this and learn something new in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signals `clock_div`, `servoPin` are driven by **multiple drivers**. You have driven `servoPin` as an output from `get_servo` module and from the testbench, `clk_tb` itself. This is illegal.

Regarding `clock_div`, refer to the figure below:

[image: Port connection rules]

The **output** of module must be connected to a **wire**. Here, `clock_div` is an output port, of `clock_divider` module, it **must be of wire type**. Then that output wire can be used as an input for your logic to drive `servoPin` module. Following is a snippet from your testbench code:

```
reg clock;
reg reset;
reg servoPin;
// reg clock_div; // remove this
wire clock_div_w, clock_div_w2;
assign clock_div_w2 = clock_div_w; // drive output from one module to input to another
//...
clock_divider DUT1 (clock, reset, clock_div_w); // wire output
get_servo DUT2 (clock_div_w2, servoPin, ding);  // another wire input
//...
initial begin
    // servoPin = 1'b1; // donot drive from here, module output
    #1 clock_div = 1'b0;
    $finish;
end
```

Similar remarks applies to `ding` port.

Referring to [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), Section 23.3.3:

> Each port connection shall be a **continuous assignment** of **source to
>   sink**, where one connected item shall be a signal source and the other
>   shall be a signal sink. The assignment shall be a continuous
>   assignment from source to sink for input or output ports.

When the ports are connected in an **instantiation**, to any other port, it is a **constant assignment**, and hence it always requires the **target port to be a net**.

Refer to [Port connection rules question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219047/port-connection-rules-in-verilog) for more information.

Comment: @Dwiref Oza: In addition to Sharvil's answer, add some delay before calling system task `$finish`, you are ended-up in simulation only after `#1`,  

#<delay> $finish; 

near to endmodule of testbench.